# Silverlight entity-level validation with MVVM

Tags: silverlight, validation, mvvm

I try to adopt entity-level validation (attributes validation on properties on entities) by create ViewModel that expose that Entity.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyEntity MyEntity { get; set; }
}
```

I set binding in xaml to, this xaml page set its DataContext to instance of MyViewModel

```
TextBlock Text="{Binding MyEntity.MyProperty}"
```

When I load MyEntity from database and set it to MyViewModel, nothing happen. I also call `NotifyPropertyChanged("MyEntity");` and it still nothing happen.

I try again by create MyProperty in MyViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private MyEntity MyEntity { get; set; }

    public string MyProperty 
    {
        get { return this.MyEntity.MyProperty; }
        set { this.MyEntity.MyProperty = value; }
    }
}
```

And changed xaml to bind to MyProperty. This time when I call NotifyPropertyChanged("MyProperty "); View get update correctly, when I input incorrect data, it has ValidationErrors at MyEntity but View don't raise that error (not show red border)

I want to know how can I get entity-level validation working with MVVM.

Comment: It would help if you could show us: A) The MyEntity class B) The XAML

Answer (score 2):

Hi
you must change the definition of ViewModel such as

```
public class MyViewModel:IDataErrorInfo
{
}
```

and implement interface.
this force View to show red border on error.
wish to help.